# Cordava installation Error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli

I tried to install apache cordava using npm command "npm install -g cordava". Every time it shows error 404 cordava not present in npm registry.
How to fix this and install latest version of Cordova?

Comment: Just a thought: I see you typoed "cordova" as "cordava" in a couple places, could this be the cause?

Comment: It's CORDOVA not cordava, try again and let us know if where was the problem

Comment: Thanks u so much @jhh0off02.. It solved my problem and after two days of trying to install I finally got it installed

Comment: Thanks u guys. Idid not expect this fast reply. Anyway u guys solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command `npm install -g cordova` instead of `npm install -g cordava`.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct spelling `cordava` to `cordova` and use following command npm install -g cordova.
Please make sure you install `node.js`. Also if you get problem again then open terminal as administrative permission and run the command again